# In django query filter for empty FileField

Tags: django

I need to filter a QuerySet by a FileField to get only the records where there is no file set on a FileField. Or the vice versa case, only the records with a file set on a FielField.

Similar to this:

```
SomeModel.objects.exclude(
    entry__relation__filefieldname=<set_to_something>
)
```

or

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(
    entry__relation__filefieldname=<not_set_at_all>
)
```

Using Q-objects does not help.

```
SomeModel.objects.exclude(
    Q(otherfieldname=None) & Q(filefieldname__isnull=True)                                                                                                                      
)
```

How do i achieve it ?

Comment: Try empty string, like: `filefieldname__upload_to=""`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But this throws an exception. Unsupported lookup 'upload_to' for FileField or join on the field not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like testing the FileField against an empty string is the solution.

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(
    entry__relation__filefieldname=""
)
```

to include in the result set only the records with the FileFields with no file set or

```
SomeModel.objects.exclude(
    entry__relation__filefieldname=""
)
```

to get a result set with records where the FielField ist set to a file.